# Python - How to read file one character at a time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-handling

I am learning python file handling. I tried this code to read one character at a time

```
f = open('test.dat', 'r')

while (ch=f.read(1)):
    print ch
```

Why it's not working

**Here is Error message**

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Users/X/PycharmProjects/Learning Python/01.py"
File "C:/Users/X/PycharmProjects/Learning Python/01.py", line 4
while (ch=f.read(1)):
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: One *character* at a time or one *byte* at a time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off, your assignment inside the while statement is invalid syntax:

```
f = open('test.dat', 'r')
while True:
    ch=f.read(1)
    if not ch: break
    print ch
```

This will start the while loop, and break it when there are no characters left to read! Give it a try.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the two form version of `iter` as an alternative to a `while` loop:

```
for ch in iter(lambda: f.read(1), ''):
    print ch
```

Answer (score 1):

For python 3.8+ you can just do this:

```py
with open("test.dat", "r") as f:
    while ch := f.read(1):
        ...
```

The walrus operator was added in Python 3.8 and it lets you use assignment as an expression!